# react redirect to only load 1 component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i tried using redirect to after using search in my react app, search works well and nothing wrong with it. the problem is, when it redirect to the search page, the component loaded is only the search component and the header component.

this is my router code:

```
<HashRouter>
  <div>
  <Master/>
  <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route exact path="/search/:userId" component={Search} />
    <Route exact path="/produk/:userId" component={Product} />
    </Switch>
    </div>
    </HashRouter>
```

and this is my master.js (header with the search)

```
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {cari: '', diCari:false};

    this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange1(e){
    this.setState({
      cari: e.target.value
    })
  }
  handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const cari = {
      cari: this.state.cari
    }

        this.setState({ diCari: true }); // after signing up, set the state to true. This will trigger a re-render

}

  render(){
    if (this.state.diCari) {
     // redirect to home if signed up
     return <Redirect to = {{ pathname: "/search/" + this.state.cari }} />;
   }
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: `this.state.cari` is this a typo? It should be `this.state.diCari` ?

Comment: no, this.state.cari is a value of the search input. nothing wrong with search just like i said

Comment: Can you create code snippet,So that everyone can get better idea?

Comment: @NaufalSyauqi can you write the full code of search and header component?

Comment: Can you add the code that call `handleSubmit` and `handleChange1`?

Comment: @AtinSingh for what? like i said, there's nothing wrong with the search its just the redirection that didn't load master.js component

Comment: okay then what is `const cari = {
      cari: this.state.cari
    }` doing in handleSubmit? Can you just post the whole code so that i can create a codebox sanbox to see what's wrong?

Comment: @AtinSingh i use it for the parameter on redirect to

Answer (score 0):

```
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Master />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={props => <Home />} />
            <Route path="/home" render={props => <Home />} />
            <Route path="/login" render={props => <Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" render={props => <Register />} />
            <Route exact path="/search/:userId" render={props => <Search />} />
            <Route exact path="/produk/:userId" render={props => <Product />} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>

      and this is my master.js(header with the search)


      render(){
        if (this.state.diCari) {
          // redirect to home if signed up
          return <Redirect to={`/search/${this.state.cari}`} />;
        }
```

make this changes and check

Comment: make changes in redirect and check